# build multiple objects with a single factory with FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Is it possible to have a factory that is *not* associated to a specific ActiveRecord model?  Instead: the factory's only purpose is to build a bunch of *other* objects:

```
# test/factories/address_options.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :address_option do

    trait :create_them do
      after(:create) do
                 create(:state)
        county = create(:county)
                 create(:city, county: county)
                 create(:zip_code)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Ex: desired usage would be: `create(:address_option, :create_them)`

This of course doesn't work because there is no `AddressOption` class, much less an `address_options` table.    The error I get is:

> NameError: uninitialized constant AddressOption

I am aware that I could simply create a `trait` on one of the factories that are associated to a real activerecord object.  But this is a bit different because I am creating a sort of "aggregate" factory: a factory that creates a bunch of objects where some of them are associated to each other while others have no association, but all objects are still related.

Comment: Why don't you just create a helper method? What is the benefit of a factory over a simple method?

Comment: @spickermann got a working solution based off of your recommendation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution based on suggestion in comments.  I am not sure if this is considered "best practice" for using factories, but it is at least a working solution for representing an abstract "aggregate" factory:

```
# test/factories/aggregates/address_option.rb
class AddressOption
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  def create_them
             create(:state)
    county = create(:county)
             create(:city, county: county)
             create(:zip_code)
  end
end
```

**usage**: `AddressOption.new.create_them`